# ¿Cómo puedo detectar una sublista que contengan solo números consecutivos de una lista?

Tags: python

```
continuos = []
i = 0
numeros = [1,2,3,7,5,10,25,65,7,8,9]
for valor in numeros:
    if numeros[i+1] == valor + 1 or numeros[i-1] == valor - 1: 
        continuos.append(valor)
        i = i + 1
        print(i)
print(continuos)
```

Tengo un archivo con fechas con formato (año mes dia) como el ejemplo (resalto los días consecutivos)

1950/ 1/   24

- 1950/ 1/   31

  1950/ 2/   1

  1950/ 2/   2

1950/ 2/   28

1950/ 12/  1

- 1950/ 12 /  31
  1951/ 1 /    1

  1951/ 1 /   2

Quiero obtener una sublista que me indique el rango de los dias consecutivos que encontró por ejemplo el output para esto quedaría así [3, 3] ya que 3 y 3 fueron los dias consecutivos que encontro, tomar en cuenta los meses ya que estoy manejando diciembre, enero y febero, he intentando hacer un pequeño ejemplo con una lista pero no logro dar
pero no logro dar con el agoritmo correcto, de ante mano gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Chicxulub a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Podrías poner el/los algoritmos que probaste, así a partir de allí podemos avanzar hacia algo que te sirva.

Comment: @JuanPablo Gracias, agregue un pequeño ejemplo que estaba resolviendo con un lista

Comment: La verdad que no se entiende bien qué es lo que deseas lograr. En el código, ¿qué significado tiene la lista _numeros_? ¿Exactamente qué salida querés lograr? ¿Qué significado tiene la salida [3,3]? Es decir, ¿no te importan los días en sí, sino la cantidad de días consecutivos únicamente?

Answer (score 1):

Si trabajas con fechas debes de usar el módulo *datetime* y si vas a hacer operaciones con ellas también debes de usar el módulo *timedelta* que está incluido dentro de *datetime*

Primero necesitamos convertir tus fechas (en formato string) a verdaderamente fechas (formato datetime), y eso lo hacemos con el método `strptime()`.

```py
#importamos modulos
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#lista de fechas
fechas = [
          "1950/1/24",
          "1950/1/31",
          "1950/2/1",
          "1950/2/2",
          "1950/2/28",
          "1950/12/1",
          "1950/12/31",
          "1951/1/1",
          "1951/1/2"
]
```

Para tener el trabajo mucho más facil vamos a ordenar esa lista según su año, eso lo hacemos mediante la función `sorted()` y usamos su parámetro `key` para especificarle que lo haga según el año, pero como especificamos eso? dado que después del año existe una `/` obtendremos el índice de esa barra y utilizaremos slice `fecha[:fecha.index("/")]`. Luego solo tendremos que iterar y converitir cada string en datetime.

```py
#ordenamos
orde = sorted(fechas,key=lambda x: x[:x.index("/")])

#convertimos a datetime mediante una compresión de lista
orde = [datetime.strptime(f,"%Y/%m/%d") for f in orde]
```

Bien con eso ya tenemos casi todo listo, para almacenar un rango de fechas `[ini,fin]` utilizaré la notación de *slices* `[inicio:fin:paso]` donde solo usaré `inicio` y `fin`, recordemos que esto actúa en base a los índices de un objeto, el `inicio` indica desde donde se toma (teniendo en cuenta el propio índice, si es 0 empieza desde 0) y el `fin` indica hasta donde, no toma en cuenta el propio índice, ósea lo toma hasta `fin-1`. Dada la forma en que elaboré mi programa siempre se almacena una lista de 2 elementos `[ini,fin]` si se establece un rango se toma en cuenta la notación de *slices* por lo que se guarda `[inim,fin+1]` pero para elementos únicos solo se almacena 2 veces el índice `[ini,ini]`

Para hacer la comprobación de si la fecha actual es consecutiva a la siguiente, solo sumamos 1 día a la fecha actual y la comparamos con la siguiente en la lista y de acuerdo a eso agregamos, para hacer el *rango* nos ayudamos de un `if` el cual comprueba si la fecha actual ya ha sido agregada y si es así suma 1 al `fin` del dato agregado anteriormente.

```py
seguido = []
for i in range(len(orde)-1):
    if orde[i]+timedelta(days=1) == orde[i+1]: #si es consecutivo
        #si no hay elementos en la lista o si la fecha ya no es consecutiva
        if len(seguido)==0 or seguido[-1][1] != i+1:
            #agregamos el elemento desde la posicion actual hasta i+2
            seguido.append([i,i+2]) 
        else: #en caso la fecha siga siendo consecutiva
            seguido[-1][1] = i+2 #sumamos 1 al "fin"
    else: #en caso no sea consecutivo
        seguido.append([i,i]) #guardamos el elemento actual

print(seguido)
```

Esto da como resultado

```
[[0, 0], [1, 4], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 9]]
```

Como dije, para las fechas únicas se guarda en las 2 posiciones la posicion de la fecha, pero para los rangos se emplea la notación de *slice* teniendo en cuenta que el `fin` es tomado como `fin-1`

Answer (score 0):

De lo que entendí (ya que no me aclaraste más), y después de la gran explicación de **Christian**, te comparto un pequeño código con un enfoque algo distinto, que te había escrito, solo que había quedado a la espera de que me aclararas un poco más qué es lo que querías.

Comparto totalmente que para gestionar fechas deberías usar la librería [datetime](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html), salvo que el objetivo sea crear un algoritmo que manipule adecuadamente el calendario (seguro que no es el caso).

Otra cosa que me parece muy importante a tener en cuenta, es usar nombres adecuados de variables, cada uno tiene su forma (yo no suelo escatimar caracteres), pero independientemente del estilo de cada uno, la idea principal es que **los nombres de las variables documenten el código.**

```
import datetime as dt


dias_consecutivos = []
fechas = ((1950, 1, 24),
          (1950, 1, 31),
          (1950, 2, 1),
          (1950, 2, 2),
          (1950, 2, 28),
          (1950, 12, 1),
          (1950, 12, 31),
          (1951, 1, 1),
          (1951, 1, 2))


actual = None
contador_consecutivos = 1
for fecha in fechas:
    if actual == None:
        actual = dt.date(fecha[0], fecha[1], fecha[2])
        continue
    anterior = actual
    actual = dt.date(fecha[0], fecha[1], fecha[2])
    if actual == (anterior + dt.timedelta(1)):
        contador_consecutivos += 1
    elif contador_consecutivos > 1:
#    else:
        dias_consecutivos.append(contador_consecutivos)
        contador_consecutivos = 1

dias_consecutivos.append(contador_consecutivos)

print(dias_consecutivos)
```

Las fechas las coloqué en tuplas anidadas porque me pareció más gráfico para entender el algoritmo, pero la mejor solución es tratarlas como explicó anteriormente **Christian**

La salida es una lista que solo almacena la cantidad de fechas consecutivas por vez, nada más (eso me pareció entender que querías hacer)

Por último, al final del código, si descomentás el `else:` y comentás el `elif contador_consecutivos > 1:` anterior, la salida incluiría también las ocasiones en fechas que no son consecutivas.

- Primer caso  --> `[3, 3]`
- Segundo caso --> `[1, 3, 1, 1, 3]`

Eso es todo, espero que le sirva a la comunidad, ¡saludos!

Comment: Más que las variables documenten el código es que tengan un nombre descriptivo y al leerlo tengas la idea de que es lo que almacena

Comment: Claro @Christian, esa es una forma de documentar. Si no entiendo qué hace la variable, tengo que agregar comentarios en todas partes. De todas formas, es como me gusta pensarlo, es sólo una idea.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una alternativa corta que hace lo siguente:

1. La lista de fechas la convierte a  su equivalente númerico ordenado.
2. Con la lista de fechas numéricas obtengo los rangos de fechas que tienen dias consecutivos.
3. Obtengo el array de dias consecutivos utilizando un iterador que recorre la lista indicada anteriormente y selecciona aquellos rangos que tengan más de 1 día.
4. Mostramos el resultado.

```
from datetime import datetime
fechas=["1950/1/24",
"1950/1/31",
"1950/2/1",
"1950/2/2",
"1950/2/28",
"1950/12/1",
"1950/12/31",
"1951/1/1",
"1951/1/2"]
# Convertimos al equivalente númerico
fecha2nums=sorted(list(map(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,"%Y/%m/%d").toordinal(),fechas)))

# Obtenemos los rangos entre fechas000
rangos = sum((list(t) for t in zip(fecha2nums, fecha2nums[1:]) if t[0]+1 != t[1]), [])

# Preparamos iterador00
iterRangos = iter(fecha2nums[0:1] + rangos + fecha2nums[-1:])

# Obtenemos lo que queremos
continuos=[n2-n1+1 for (n1,n2) in [(n,next(iterRangos)) for n in iterRangos] if(n2-n1)>0]

print(continuos)
```

El resultado será: [3,3]